# INNER JOIN on VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, sql, join, varchar

The following query returns 0 rows, even though the two tables contain several matching values.

```
SELECT i.isrc, m.isrc FROM table1 i INNER JOIN table2 m ON i.isrc = m.isrc;
```

Because the isrc column is a varchar type, I suspected it might be a problem with the table collation. Changing both collations to utf-8, however, did not fix the problem.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure the values match?

Comment: When joining on varchar, it's easy for blank spaces and invisible characters to prevent matches, when they look like they should match.

Comment: Try trimming and upper/lower casing both values.

Comment: I did check that, yes. I ran the following SELECT statements on both tables and received matching rows for both tables: SELECT isrc FROM table WHERE isrc = "value";

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) that duplicates the problem?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK I also tried "ON trim(i.isrc) = trim(m.isrc)". Is that what you mean?

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding, not a collation. Encodings should not affect matches at all. The collation bit is the `_ci`, `_cs`... suffix.

Comment: @DigitalMusicology yes, but try include the UCASE/LCASE also

Comment: I suspect the “matching” values use different code points; copy them from your table and paste them to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below,

```
SELECT i.isrc, m.isrc 
FROM table1 i 
INNER JOIN table2 m
ON UPPER(TRIM(i.isrc)) = UPPER(TRIM(m.isrc))
```

**NOTE:**

1. Trim the values on both sides
2. Normalise the case

Comment: Hardcore anti "stupid mistake" code there. I like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what you *think* are matching values in each table:

```
select src, sum(in1) as in1, sum(in2) as in2
from ((select distinct i.isrc as src, 1 as in1, 0 as in2 from table1 i) union all
      (select distinct m.isrc as src, 0 as in1, 1 as in2 from table1 m)
     ) t
group by src;
```

Before doing the above, you might find a summary helpful:

```
select in1, in2, count(*), min(src), max(src)
from (select src, sum(in1) as in1, sum(in2) as in2
      from ((select distinct i.isrc as src, 1 as in1, 0 as in2 from table1 i) union all
            (select distinct m.isrc as src, 0 as in1, 1 as in2 from table1 m)
           ) t
      group by src
     ) s
group by in1, in2;
```

The semantics for being the same for a `group by` and being the same for a comparison might not be the same (spaces at the end will affect similarity for `group by` but shouldn't affect similarity for equality, for instance).  However, this will let you know what could be matching across the two tables.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. This confirms that identical values are not detected. I am still unclear as to why. I tried to trim() and upper() the values. To my eyes they are identical and separate SELECT statements with matching values in the two tables return the corresponding rows.