# MySQL updating column in table 1 based on results of INNER JOIN with table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am moving data around between mysql tables. I am trying to do an inner join and then mirror columnX in company table to columnX in people table.

```
UPDATE people
INNER JOIN company on people.currCompId=company.itemId
SET people.companyId = company.id;
```

This doesn't work despite me doing a similar join on another table and moving data across successfully. So I tried a simple SELECT statement using the same join, and it didn't work either:

```
SELECT people.fullName, company.id
from people
INNER JOIN company on people.currCompId=company.itemId;
```

If anyone can shed any light on why the update statement fails to update anything and why the select statement does not return anything.

people.currCompId & company.itemId are both defined as VARCHAR(50), and they both contain data such as '255A7C76-A6F0-40B5-ADBA-DE290B4GG5A1', both columns have the same source for this data so I would have expected it join.

Comment: You have provided no data and no explanation of what "not working" means.  There is really no information that anyone can help you with.  Have you spelled the column names correctly?

Comment: I would have thought it was clear that "not working" in this context means a) the update statement fails to update anything b) the select statement returns nothing

Comment: If the select doesn't produce any rows, it means there is no related data present. You should provide some sample data in the question and what result you expect

Comment: the data is definitely there, I've edited the question to provide more info

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't update any records is because doesn't match any rows. E.g. following should not return any records:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
INNER JOIN company on people.currCompId=company.itemId;
```

This maybe because the query tries to join `companyId` with `itemId`? Should it not be joining `people.currComId` to `company.id`?

**Update**

Based on the example (in the updated question), it looks like both `companyId` and `itemId` are in [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) format.. If both the tables have some records then I would recommend looking a bit more into how the data is inserted into these tables. If different UUIDs are used for `Company` and `Item` (looks like it) then they won't match as UUID will almost always be unique.

Comment: SELECT * returns nothing, the columns are definitely correct.

Comment: If `SELECT` returns nothing then obviously `update` won't update any records.

Comment: yes I am very aware of that, which is why I am here asking for suggestions for why it  might not be working.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to join two `VARCHAR` columns. It's clear from your explanation that both columns you are joining have common data, so the issue should be related to how the data from both columns are compared. Now based on [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26239868/2334352), you need to make your comparison more effective. Change your query to look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
INNER JOIN company on UPPER(TRIM(people.currCompId)) = UPPER(TRIM(company.itemId));
```

Also be certain both tables you are comparing have the same character set for comparisons to work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it returns no rows, to make absolutely sure the columns have some values in common I have also run a  "SELECT * FROM WHERE LIKE" and confirmed there are values in common.

Comment: @schnimmy do both tables have the same character set and collation?

Comment: both company and people have the same collation(utf8_general_ci), but the relevant column in people was imported from another table that is latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: @schnimmy try changing the collation before comparing both columns. Make sure they are both identical